# Writing test cases for application that uses jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

I have just started writing test cases for my project and i am new to this . Its a Maven restful web project -- jersey framework . I use MySql database . I want to write test cases for methods that interact with DB(JDBC) . I want to know the references from where i can learn these things . I want to write test cases using JDBC not HSQL . If anyone can tell me where to look for . It would be very helpful..
thanks in advance.

Comment: Some keywords for you: Dependency Injection (DI), Inversion of Control (IoC), Mocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Isolate all usages of JDBC in dedicated classes (DAOs - Data Access Objects), doing just that: database queries. Don't return ResultSets from these methods. Return collections of objects.
2. Use a dependency injection framework (CDI, Spring, Guice, etc.) to inject DAOs into classes (services) needing to execute queries. These classes will only use DAO methods to execute those queries.
3. Test these services by injecting mock DAOs, returning what you tell them to return. That allows testing the business logic in the services without needing any database. [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), for example, is useful to create the mocks. To inject them, you don't need any framework here. Just call a constructor or a setter and pass the mock DAOs.
4. Test your DAOs with a real database, and make sure each test populates the database with the just the necessary data for the test. A tool like [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/) or [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) is useful to do that.